# .get function Data to Panda Dataframe gives TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I tried alot to finde an answer for the Error but didn't finde one.
I have a Radio button and other fields, and want the data set to be exported to a csv file.

I try to post the relevant snippets of the code:

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    def set_department(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.selected_department = self.department.get() #get the selected Radio button for deparment
        self.selected_area = self.Bereich.get()          #get selected Radio button for working place
        .
        .
        .

    def save_data_to_file(self):

        df_save_to_file = pd.DataFrame[['Eintragsnummer',str(self.department.get())]]
        print(df_save_to_file)
```

I can't run the script, because it gives following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Fehlerliste.py", line 499, in <module>
    app = App()
  File "C:\Fehlerliste.py", line 482, in __init__
    self.btn_entry = ttk.Button(self, text = 'in Fehlerliste eintragen', command= self.save_data_to_file())
  File "C:\Fehlerliste.py", line 47, in save_data_to_file
    df_save_to_file = pd.DataFrame[['Eintragsnummer',str(self.department.get())]]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't know Python very well, but I have the feeling the reason may be that I did not declare the variable self.department. But I must say I do not even know how, because if I declare

```
self.department = ""
```

I do not know who far to indent the declaration. It would not work

Comment: Should `pd.DataFrame[[...]]` be `pd.DataFrame([...])` instead?

Comment: Thank you, such a stupid mistake ! , although I wanted ```pd.DataFrame([[...]])```